# Dimension of artin stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I was reading the article of Laumon 1988: Un analogue global du cone nilpotent (I am sorry but I could not find an available link to share).

He fixes a curve $X$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) and considers the algebraic stack $\operatorname{Fib}^{\lambda}_{X,\nu}$ of line bundles on $X$ of generic rank $\nu$ and generic degree $\lambda$ (actually, he does the work for filtrations of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, but it does not matter here).

In corollary 2.10 he proves that this stack is smooth and then computes its dimension at a point $\mathcal{L}$ using the Euler characteristic $\chi(Hom(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}))$ (so the dimension is $(\nu-1)g^2$ by Riemann-Roch, if $g$ is the genus of $X$).

Question 1: is there a reference for why one can compute the dimension of a smooth algebraic stack in this way? It seems that locally at $\mathcal{L}$ the stack is isomorphic to $[Ext(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L})/Hom(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L})]$, how would you prove it?

Question 2: is smoothness necessary for the computation of the dimension? For example, if $X$ is a surface, can I still compute the dimension of the (algebraic, but not smooth) stack at a point $\mathcal{L}$ as $-\chi(Hom(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}))$?

Comment: Once you know the stack is smooth, its dimension can be computed as the Euler characteristic of the tangent complex. This is what Laumon is doing (the cohomology of the tangent complex are Hom(L,L) and Ext^1(L,L)). So basically, this is deformation theory.

Comment: Ok, so what about the same problem but for a surface $X$? Can one adopt similar techniques to compute the dimension at a point? Is it even known?

Comment: what is the (generic) rank of a line bundle ? Do you mean vector bundle instead ?

Comment: First of all (assuming you are not dealing with derived stacks), the tangent complex sees only $Hom$ and $Ext^1$, while the Euler characteristic sees all $Ext$'s. This is why the case of curve is somewhat special (no $Ext$'s past the first). A nice example is the stack of torsion sheaves of fixed length (say, n) on a smooth surface: the stack has dimension n (and in fact it is smooth), but $\chi(RHom(F,F))=0$ for any torsion sheaf $F$. The discrepancy is due to $Ext^2(F,F)$, which is $n$-dimensional.

Comment: Secondly, if the stack is not known to be smooth, there may be disagreement between its dimension and the Euler characteristic of the tangent complex. This is already true for schemes: if a scheme is non-reduced, the tangent space at all points is going to have higher dimension than the dimension of the scheme. So you'd need some extra arguments to compute the dimension via deformation theory in the singular case...