# Reference for calculating the dimension of algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I am interested in the dimension of algebraic stacks.But, I’m in trouble because I can’t calculate it.Are there any good reference or tools for calculating it? 
I use the “Champs algébriques” by Laumon & Moret - Bailly as a reference for its definition.

Edit:In particular,I want to calculate the dimension of moduli stacks of coherent sheaves and filtered(flag) coherent sheaves.

Comment: Could discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275637/dimension-of-artin-stacks be of some help?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.I have some questions.I don’t know tangent complex’s(which t3suji said.).Could you tell me tangent complexes or some reference for tangent complexes.And I want to calculate the dimensions in the case of projective surfaces (in the cases ,I don’t know smoothness of the moduli stacks of coherent sheaves even if I only think about torsion-free sheaves.)And I am thinking estimating the dimensions by them of filtered sheaves.Are there any tools to do it?